# Sorting Excel Grids - Sort function vs Filters

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Wondering if using Filters is recommended as opposed to using the Sort function in Excel? I ask because I find that when I use filters, sometimes the last column doesn't sort with the rest of the data. I have been told that you need to assign filters to all columns (to infinity). I have always just deleted all filters first then used the Sort function, but maybe I shouldn't be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to AutoFilter (built-in feature) or FILTER function?

As far as I know, neither the AutoFilter nor the FILTER function can sort the data.

You should refer to those links to learn the difference and function of them:

[Filter data in a range or table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e)

[FILTER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

[SORT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c)